For each $a > 1$, $\left]\frac{3^a}{2^a},\ \frac{3^a-1}{2^a-1}\right[ $ does not contain a Natural number
I am struggling with the proof of the following lemma:
$\forall a > 1, \ 3^a = 2^a q + r, \ 0 < r < 2^a \Rightarrow 1 < q + r < 2^a$
This lemma allows deriving $3^a - 1 = (2^a - 1) q + (q+r-1)$, with $0 < q+r-1 < 2^a - 1$.
Consequently, $\forall a > 1, \left]\dfrac{3^a}{2^a},\ \dfrac{3^a-1}{2^a-1}\right[ \cap \mathbb{N} = \emptyset$ which is my demonstration objective.
Any help or alternative approaches would be greatly appreciated.

What's this notation

@Gwen it is an alternative notation for open intervals

The interval being open, this also holds for $a=1$. Therefore, we could reformulate it as $\forall a \in \mathbb{N}^*, \left]\frac{3^a}{2^a},\ \frac{3^a-1}{2^a-1}\right[ \cap \mathbb{N} = \emptyset$.

Title: An interval usually is not a number anyway. You mean, the interval doesn't contain a natural number.

Given that this would immediately imply the "important unsolved problem related to Waring's problem to show that $\lfloor \frac{3^n}{2^n} \rfloor = \lfloor \frac{ 3^n - 1 } { 2^n - 1 } \rfloor$" (See OEIS first comment), I'm going to go out on a limb and say that your "lemma" isn't easy or obvious.
